# Song that plays in Christmas episode of Season 2 of Grey's Anatomy?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I just watched a episode of Grey's Anatomy in Season 2. It is the episode where the time is for Christmas. A kid gets a heart transplant and Karev is studying for his boards.

There's a song which I'd like to know that plays out in the latter half of the episode.

Does anybody know it?

Comment: @Tetsujin um..I guess I found the song at http://greysanatomy.wikia.com/wiki/Grandma_Got_Run_Over_By_a_Reindeer what should I do? Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can answer your own question - see https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Welcome - I think you may have to wait a day or two, but eventually you will also be able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The song was "It Came Upon The Midnight Clear".

The one I was looking for was a version done by Sixpence None The Richer. You can listen to it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jH0HDNTrHFw